# Scheduled reports using java/postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I have a form (which permits to give a periodicity, a frequency, a start date etc.. in the goal of schedule a postgres query task and then send emails (each week, month.....)) in my web application and I would like to know what is the best solution to schedule these queries.

I tried to use a simple Timer() (which works) but it doesn't launch a new thread and doesn't leave the program to continue.

I read some articles on @scheduled annotations of spring but I have understood that I cant give parameters to the annotations from my form map. If anyone has an idea, thank you very much!
Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a schedule task in spring to run every 5 seconds say, then get it to check if an email is due, don't try and change the scheduler timing, change the logic :

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void sendEmails() {
    // add logic here to decide if the email actually has to be sent, if not
    // do nothing
}
```

Don't forget to add the @EnableScheduling to your config

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringConfig {
    ...
}
```

See [example here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didnt see things in this way !

Comment: @Lexahen would you accept my answer and up vote if you're happy. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I am sorry i did not see the green tick ! edit: (it makes too much things i did not see ahah)